# Map with Icons as Labels in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying already for awhile to find a solution for creating a map with different categories on it shown.

I have only longitude and latitude, no location columns. I merged already into one table different data points from different tables in my database, which are shown as categories. So, it shows as labels in different colors. For example, if it's a coordinates of organization, it shows in one color, if its user - shows in different color. But i want them to be shown as icons, not colors or at least modify the colors of bubbles it shows on dot map.

I also need it to show the name of organization when hovering over the data point.

I have already tried to find solution in all integrated maps of Power BI as well as downloaded add-on called icon map. but it still doesn't work. Dot map doesn't have an option to modify labels, not even colors. Azure Maps is the best option, but it doesn't fully work without location field as well.

Did anyone had similar project and found the solution by any chance?

Thanks a lot!